# Sort Java List from closest to farthest (with multiple keys)

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, arraylist, closest

I wish to sort a Java list from closest to farthest relative to a particular value.

**For example :**

the list :

```
{4,5,8,4,5,1,2,10,1,0,12}
```

for a comparison oh the value **3** would becomes :

```
{4,4,5,5,2,1,1,0,8,10,12}
```

Thus, the first values are at a distance of 1 to number 3 and those at the distance of 2 of the number 3 ...

I tried an ArrayList with a Comparator, but I do not see how to compare two by two. But also with a treemap distances but the keys need not be unique.

I hope to have been clear!

Do you have a solution ?
Thank you

Comment: You compare by calculating which one is closer to 3.

Comment: Can you show your comparator, please?

Comment: why 2 is farther than 5? the distance from 2 is 1, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> arr = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 1, 2, 10, 1, 0, 12);
        final int pivot = 3;

        Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
                int d1 = Math.abs(a - pivot);
                int d2 = Math.abs(b - pivot);
                return Integer.compare(d1, d2);
            }
        });

        System.out.println(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution by creating custom `Comparator` :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 1, 2, 10, 1, 0, 12);
        System.out.println(list);
        list.sort(new CustomComparator(3));
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}

class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Integer>
{

    private int value;

    public CustomComparator(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2)
    {
        return Integer.compare(Math.abs(o1 - value), Math.abs(o2 - value));
    }
}
```

The output is :

```
[4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 1, 2, 10, 1, 0, 12]
[4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 1, 1, 0, 8, 10, 12]
```